# Is there a Jewish source for the saying: "only the father knows when the wedding would take place"?

Tags: marriage, wedding, christianity, mesorah-tradition, judaism

The website below describes what is apparently an ancient Jewish wedding custom, in which it was apparently said that "only the Father" of the groom "knows" when the wedding would take place.:

> [I]n order to maintain the respect and dignity of the father’s
> place in the home, it would naturally be said “that only the father
> knows” when it would be time for the son to go get the bride.  This
> did not necessitate that the son did not know because the community
> would have to know within a reasonable degree of accuracy when the
> wedding would occur.  ([Source](https://carm.org/bible-difficulties/if-the-holy-spirit-is-god-why-didnt-he-know-the-time-of-christs-return-man/))

Is there a source for this practice within the traditions of Judaism?

Comment: The OP is asking whether there is any "Jewishness" about this custom mentioned in his source. Whether the source is suitable for this stackexhange does not matter, since this is a Judaism-related question, not about the Christian background. Please correct me if I'm wrong in this..... The OP could edit his question to make it more suitable.

Comment: @Shmuel Yes thank you! The question really has nothing to do with Christianity. It is simply about whether or not the practice described in the source is rooted in Jewish tradition.

Comment: Then you should edit your question, to make it more suitable for this site.

Comment: @Shmuel i already did

Comment: I think, to be honest, that the first two customs are not really customs, but common sense. An invitation, back then, needed way more effort than nowadays, when we have mail and other forms of communication. I think that the main question should be focused on if there is a Jewish source on the saying "only the father knows" when it would be time for the son to go get the bride.

Comment: Never heard of that.

Comment: No, the choice to marry (and thus the timing thereof) is entirely up to the couple. It is proper for them to account for the advice, suggestions, requests, etc. of their respective parents, however ultimately these decisions are theirs alone to make. Accordingly, only the couple knows when the marriage will take place - everyone else is informed of their decision.

Comment: @Deuteronomy unless she's under 12, which probably happened regularly at that time